# Java и Android: литература

Tags: android, java

Решил начать программировать на мобильные системы, хотел с iOS начать, но ввиду отсутствия мака... В общем, начать решил с Java, писать на Android. Есть ли какие книги на русском для этого? Яву не знаю абсолютно, но неплохо знаю С++, также писал программки на Qt (я бы на Qt и писал, но так и не разобрался, можно ли компилировать для телефончиков/планшетов под Android. Если можно, хотелось бы узнать как). Слышал, что плюсы и ява похожи, надеюсь на это.

Comment: а вы искать в гугле пробовали? Ваш вопрос, наверно, уже тыщь десять раз задавался.

Comment: > неплохо знаю С++

от скромности не умрете

Comment: Я не написал: "полностью знаю С++", "Я эксперт в плюсах", просто имел в виду, что язык более-менее знаю (такая конструкция вас удовлетворит?). Насчет гугла - спасибо, я никогда не слышал о такой вещи! Про Яву есть куча книг, но мне нужна книга с уклоном на андроид, и я не знаю, какая лучше. По какой книге вы учили?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1zhW23H вот ссылка. там есть

Comment: ни чего по книгам не учу в принципе. Это крайне неэффективно. Либо видеоуроки, либо специализированные курсы.

Comment: >Я не написал: "полностью знаю С++", "Я эксперт в плюсах", просто имел в виду, что язык более-менее знаю

не сочтите за придирку. Однако плюсы - язык достаточно специфический, и даже чтобы его "неплохо знать", надо весьма постараться.

>ни чего по книгам не учу в принципе. Это крайне неэффективно. Либо видеоуроки, либо специализированные курсы.

facepalm

Comment: @DreamChild, очень даже верно, в языке очень много нюансов, о которых нужно и в то же время невозможно помнить. Но тем не менее, по теме есть что-нибудь? Гугл никогда верно не ответит на запрос "хорошая книга по программированию на андройд", спасибо авторам за жизнерадостные аннотации к их книгам.

Comment: @master_clown хорошая книга это та, после ПРОЧТЕНИЯ которой ты можеш сказать - да, это была хороша книга. Вывод - никто не знает, что для тебя окажется хорошей книгой. Конечно, есть плохие книги, по 200-300 страниц с названиями а-ля "андроид для чайников". Такое разве что в туалете пригодится

Comment: @argamidon, очень хорошо, ответить на вопрос > По какой книге вы учили?

невозможно. Философские изыскания по вопросу "Почему одному хорошо одно, другому - другое", думаю, можно хотя бы на время отложить.

Comment: мой выбор может не понравится многим, но вот хорошая книга для меня [link text][1]


  [1]: http://www.apress.com/9781430231561

Comment: @master_clown [вот эту книжку][1] многие хвалят. Сам о ней ничего не скажу, поскольку еще не читал

[1]:http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21469100/

Answer (score 3):

Одной книжкой никогда не обойтись. Вот мой набор (попроще и посложнее):

1. Голощапов А.Л. - Google Android. Программирование для мобильных устройств
2. Рето Майер - Android 4. Программирование приложений
3. Хашими С., Коматинени С., Маклин Д. - Разработка приложений для Android - 2011
4. Android Recipes A Problem-Solution Approach By Dave Smith , Jeff Friesen.

Comment: Значит я не прогадал, а то от временного чувства безысходности я скачал первую книжку. Потом где-то прочитал, что это вроде как перевод официальной документации. Что ж, спасибо!

Comment: наздоровье. Вот только я когда задавался подобным вопросом тоже, типа "с чего начать изучать андроид". Совет и пару ссылок получил, начал читать, но это оказалось таким дерьмом, что пришлось самому побродить по интернету и найти достойное себя. Каждому своё.
ЗЫ первая книжка в списке самая простая, черезчур даже

Answer (score 3):

> В общем, начать решил с Java, писать на Android. ... Яву не знаю абсолютно

Ради всего святого, начните с изучения Java (тут не раз писали с чего именно). Как освоитесь - принимайтесь за Android API Guide http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html и прочие ресурсы, которые вам тут накидают.

В противном случае вы погрязнете в вопросах, почему при сравнении строк ничего не получается и куда девается вся память.

Comment: яростно плюсую. Незная основ - нефиг фреймворки изучать.

Answer (score 1):

Startandroid.ru - хороший ресурс с уроками. И скоро начнется курс по андроид на курсере. И еще, большая просьба не называйте джаву явой)

Comment: Честно говоря я терпеть не могу видеокурсы, лично мне легче читать, чем слушать. Мне главное начать и начать с легко читаемой книги (и тут я подразумеваю не количество информации, а грамматическую ясность). Ну и на русском штоб была)

Comment: Так зайдите на startandroid. Там текстовые уроки.

Comment: @master_clown, я тоже очень долго писал на Си. Как-то понадобилась Java (правда, к андроиду отношения не имеет).

Так вот, из нескольких прочитанных книг, пожялуй, больше всего понравилась [ Брюс Эккель, Философия Java](http://www.books.ru/books/filosofiya-java-biblioteka-programmista-3-e-izdanie-121331/) (ссылка попалась с кучей отзывов, в т.ч. отрицательных).

Хотя, для систематического (скажем с нуля или около того) 2 тома Java Хорстманна, наверное, лучше.

Ну, а особенности андроида, я думаю, Вы потом легко освоите.